# Referral returned when using PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to enumerate all the users of the Enterprise Admins group.

I have tried the following:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.domain,"globalcatalog.domain.local", "DC=domain,DC=local");
GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipa,FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "Enterprise Admins");

IList<string> users = new List<string>();

foreach(Principal p in grp.Getmembers(true)){
users.Add(p.Name);
}
```

Unfortunately, i will consistently get an error that says A referral was returned from the server.  Is there anything I am missing here?  I would rather not go back to using the DirectoryEntry class, but looks like I might have to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954170/a-referral-was-returned-from-the-server-exception-when-accessing-ad-from-c-sha Look at Ander's Abel answer.

Comment: I am trying to *not* use the DirectoryEntry class.  I would like to use PrincipalContext where possible, as I find the code more readable.

Comment: The answer is not about DirectoryEntry but rather about possible wrong referring to the domain controller.

Comment: The references I have are correct - using the server name in a powershell script, I am able to get the information I need.

Comment: You get the `referral` from establishing `ctx` connection or finding the group? And I'm assuming `GroupPrincipa,FindByIdentity` is a typo? It should be `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity`. Wrap those two statements in `try/catch` statement and look at the `error code`. Is the account that you're executing the code has enough rights to search AD?

Comment: The error is 1355.  The error occurs when GroupPrincipal is hit, not PrincipalContext.

Comment: What if you prefix the group name with the actual domain name? Just guessing but can't see anything obvious here.

Comment: Hm, you mean like DOMAIN\Enterprise Admins?  Yeah, this is really strange.  I can get Domain Admins just fine, but not Enterprise Admins.  When I tried using port 3268 i get an error that it cannot get info from domain.