# Set-AdUser a referral was returned from the server

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to set a new company value for users from a CSV.

I read that you get the error when not setting the server in my `Set-AdUser` command.

```
At line:18 char:18
+ ...    $query | Set-ADUser -Server tstdc01 -Company "New Company"
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (CN=testUser\, H...DC=domain,DC=local:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADReferralException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8235,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Import-Csv -Path "pathToCsv.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";"
$setUsers = @()
$domain = "domain.local:3268"
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $samAccountName = $user.samAccountName
    $query = Get-ADUser -Filter {Samaccountname -eq $samAccountName} -Server $domain
    if ($query) {
        $query | Set-ADUser -server tstdc01-Company "New Company"
        $setUsers += $query
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you working on the same Domain as the Domain you're pointing your query? Any specific reason why GC port is hardcoded on your `$domain` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Santiago implied this looks like an issue of cross domain or forest communication.  And/or you are passing a user from one domain and attempting to set it in another.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954170/a-referral-was-returned-from-the-server-exception-when-accessing-ad-from-c-sha), and a link [here](https://www.ozkary.com/2015/02/activedirectory-membership-provider.html)

An aside, a few pointers; You don't need to filter for samAccountName when you already have the samAccountName, the query can be something like:

```
$setUsers =
Get-ADUser $samAccountName -Server $domain |
ForEach-Object{
    Set-ADUser $_ -Server tstdc01 -Company "New Company" -PassThru    
}
```

Also note: you should avoid `+=` I don't know how big a job this is, but it can degrade performance as it causes the creation of a new array and a copy of the existing array.  Repeated many times that can cause big performance issues.  There are a number of ways to address that, but the preferred approach is to let PowerShell gather the results for you.  So above assign the `$setUsers` variable to the output of the loop. Add `-PassThru` to output the object that was set.

**Update:**
With the point regarding `+=` demonstrated, @SantiagoSquarzon pointed out we don't even need the loop anymore:

```
$setUsers =
Get-ADUser $samAccountName -Server $domain |
Set-ADUser -Server tstdc01 -Company "New Company" -PassThru
```

Comment: Yup, agreed. This also should work `Get-ADUser $samAccountName -Server $domain | Set-ADUser -Server tstdc01 -Company "New Company" -PassThru`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Duh why didn't I see that... I guess sometimes where you start affects where you finish.  Let me update and credit you...

Comment: That's fine you don't need to credit me, your answers are always pretty accurate :)